# I can't figure out how to update my last inlog time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an last activity function for an website. but i can't get it to work. I hope you guys can help me out here.

this is my query:

```
$last_activity_query = "UPDATE users_table SET user_name  = '$user_name' WHERE 'date_last_inlog' = NOW()";

$result_update =  mysql_query($last_activity_query);

$last_activity_update = mysql_fetch_array($result_update);
```

this is an print screen of my database table:

[image]

I want to store this update in the last row.

Thanks in advance!

i've changed my script now but its still not changing anything in my database table.

this is the change:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['inlog_submit'])){//checks if form is submitted


                    $user_name = $_REQUEST['username_input'];//request username from inlog_form
                    $password = $crypt;//gets enqrypted pass
                    //$tbl_name="user_table"; // Table name
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE user_name= '$user_name' AND password='$password'";//query stored in var
                    $last_activity_query = "UPDATE users_table SET 'date_last_inlog' = NOW() WHERE user_name  = '$user_name'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);//var with result of query
                    $result_update =  mysql_query($last_activity_query);

                    if ($user_name = mysql_fetch_array($result)){//checks inlog data from form with the $result query
                        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name[user_name];//creates session with username
                        $_SESSION['password'] = $password[password];//creates session with password
                        $last_activity_update = mysql_fetch_array($result_update);
                        header ('Location: admin.php');//when login is correct redirect to specified page
                    }else{
                        $error_inlog = 10;//when inlog data is incorrect this error will show
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: You have the logic the wrong way round. I think what you want is to `UPDATE date_last_inlog WHERE username` .

Comment: **Always** [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) your inserted values to be sure you don't suffer from severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You shouldn't even be using `mysql_query`, it's deprecated and being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will future-proof your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17707792/2288145

this is working!!

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query is in the wrong order.

```
$last_activity_query = "UPDATE users_table SET 'date_last_inlog' = NOW() WHERE user_name  = '$user_name'";
```

Comment: uhm i can't get it to work. i've edited my post with more info

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect. Use this:-

```
"UPDATE users_table SET 'date_last_inlog' = NOW() WHERE user_name  = '$user_name'";
```

You are using this :-

```
UPDATE users_table SET user_name  = '$user_name' WHERE 'date_last_inlog' = NOW()
```

You are trying to update `user_name` column where the `date_last_inlog` column value is equal to the current time which is logically incorrect.

Comment: thank you! i've changed it but it is not working yet? when i look into my database its still 0000:00:00 00:00:00