# I can't seem figure out how to update my last inlog time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an last activity function for an website. but i can't get it to work. I hope you guys can help me out here.

this is my script:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['inlog_submit'])){//checks if form is submitted


                    $user_name = $_REQUEST['username_input'];//request username from inlog_form
                    $password = $crypt;//gets enqrypted pass
                    //$tbl_name="user_table"; // Table name
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE user_name= '$user_name' AND password='$password'";//query stored in var
                    $last_activity_query = "UPDATE users_table SET 'date_last_inlog' = NOW() WHERE user_name  = '$user_name'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);//var with result of query
                    $result_update =  mysql_query($last_activity_query);

                    if ($user_name = mysql_fetch_array($result)){//checks inlog data from form with the $result query
                        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name[user_name];//creates session with username
                        $_SESSION['password'] = $password[password];//creates session with password
                        $last_activity_update = mysql_fetch_array($result_update);
                        header ('Location: admin.php');//when login is correct redirect to specified page
                    }else{
                        $error_inlog = 10;//when inlog data is incorrect this error will show
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

this is an print screen of my database table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDMGA.png

thanks in advance!

Comment: What problem are you having? Do you get a blank screen? An error message? The wrong line being updated? The right line, with the wrong data? Nothing at all being updated?

Comment: Nitpick: it's "login", not "inlog"

Comment: Your question will get closed, as duplicate of your own question :]

Comment: it actually is kind of an duplicate.. but there i didn't get an answer after i edited the post and here i do.

Comment: never every duplicate your own question. It will only get you downvotes and you'll loose potential friends.

Comment: i've tried to delete the old one but i can't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query here:

```
UPDATE users_table SET 'date_last_inlog' = NOW() WHERE user_name  = '$user_name'
```

Try removing the quotes around `date_last_inlog` or changing them to backticks:

```
UPDATE users_table SET date_last_inlog = NOW() WHERE user_name  = '$user_name'
```

Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.  Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: in other words, adding quotes to the field name turns it into a string, and it'll no longer be treated as a field name.

Comment: @simon: fine sentiment, but Eric isn't using them... the OP is. put your comment in the correct place...

Comment: @Simon_eQ - Just added that.  Should be added automatically as a standard disclaimer on all questions tagged `php` and `mysql`  :)

Comment: Thanks!! this is working! I'll look into the use of mysqli or PDO. i'm very new into this and we learn this at school. (to sad actually).. but when i run this script i still get an error showing this: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in "/filepath/" on line 82

Comment: Thanks! i now have this: $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());//var with result of query

but its still the same error

Comment: @user - actually, ignore my last comment, just remove this line: `$last_activity_update = mysql_fetch_array($result_update);`.  It's unnecessary as an update statement doesn't actually return anything (and would be why mysql_fetch_array is failing)

Comment: Please move the answer to the duplicate question. Thank you! It's sad but OP requires we need to clean up after him.

Comment: done! but i can't answer it officially because i have not enough point yet.